# 1st install just leaves a background screen!

Tags: system-installation, system

Just installed Ubuntu for the 1st time (ever!) on a Tosh Satellite L450D laptop - changing from Windows 7.

Initial issues with Disk partitions overcome - I did a complete install from CD. Asked me to apply latest update - which I did - After final reboot, all I have is the background screen, a movable mouse pointer and the ability to open the (mouse)right click menu. Absolutely nothing else, no Bar, applications, menu - Nada.

Reinstalled it all from CD again but with NO update this time - still the same.

I can change the background screen so it isn't Video and by doing that I can get the setting menus. Interestingly this menu box does not have a max, min or close button/tab at the top - so something is not right here either.

Assuming that I should have a fully working desktop - anyone can point me to whats wrong and how to fix it.

Ubuntu version - 14.04.02
Litterally 1st time user of this environment - come from Mac/Win world!

1st experience of Ubuntu - it is disappointing!

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start a terminal.

From here, type

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop
```

and <kbd>Return</kbd>.

The `sudo` password is your user password.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Really appreciated. Ctrl-Alt-T didn't work but I had seen Ctrl-Alt-F2 do the same from another post so did that, Followed your script which ran through and completed. Rebooted system - back to same desktop background, with mouse and right click menu - nothing else?  is there another trick or patch here?

Comment: Maybe try running `sudo startx`.

Comment: Hiya, I ran that and system returned to background screen. I have turned off and on - now have a login screen with the bar on the top - as it should be - now it gets stranger! If I try to log into account with correct password - screen goes black then returns to login screen - with low level drum sound! If I use an invalid password - I just get the wrong password message - no black screen as above. If I use the guest login screen - I get the orogonal problem of just background, cursor et al..Any thoughts?

Comment: just went to terminal - Ctrl, Alt F2 - to log in to check all ok - it worked fine using same credentials. However it came back - 152 packages can be updated  - 88 updates are security updates

Comment: This is a known bug with lightdm. Get gdm and set it as your main display manager. Only your login screen will change

Comment: Thanks for the response - but any chance you could put it down in a step my step approach - Although I was a Techie (years ago!) I am new to Ubuntu - big time. Its bringing back all my old DOS and unix stuff though but its 20 years ago!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gdm`. It will ask fro confirmations and such, as well as a choice for your default display manager. When this popup comes up, select `gdm`, press TAB and then Enter.

Comment: Completed and new display manager installed - Thanks. Security problem still exists but not in terminal - only in the display manager? That has me scratching head - So still can't log in...

Comment: Even in `gdm`? Weird. That fixed it for me. maybe run `sudo dpkg --configure lightdm`. Or try purging and reinstalling `lightdm`.

Comment: The configure doesn't work - already configured is the reply. Do you know why the login is now affected in the desktop but not terminal - something must be broke. Also anyone know why the desktop will not load correctly - is there a problem with Toshiba boxes?

Comment: I know it's a bug in lightdm, which prevents you from logging in. Logging into Guest or making a new account and logging into it work fine, but already-made accounts don't work.